# Why we get Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException in blazemeter while execution?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, blazemeter, jmeter-4.0

I am getting below error while executing test in blazemeter.

```
jmeter.JMeter: Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'/home/jmeter/abc.jmx', missing class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException:
```

Have anyone face this issue....

Also  i am using random csv data set plug-in in my jmeter script which i have uploaded in blazemeter.

Comment: Can you show your Blazemeter configuration and the jmeter.log ?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 possibilities:

- Either you forgot adding a plugin your test plan requires
- Or you forgot adding a dependency that a used plugin requires
- Or there is an incompatibility between the jmeter version used locally and on Blazemeter

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this issue this morning. To solve it:

1) Add the jmeter plugin manager.

2) Close jmeter and reopen it.

3) It then suggested the plugins I was missing and allowed me to add them.

It worked fine after this. Hope this helps